# How to first boot Ubuntu from a laptop on Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: 14.04, raspberrypi

I have watched many tutorials on how to boot Ubuntu on Raspberry Pi. Every time, after inserting the imaged SD card on the Pi, people attach it with a monitor and a keyboard. But if I  want to attach it with my laptop instead of a monitor, what would I have to do? How would I connect it? And if I connect the Raspberry Pi with the newly imaged sd card, will it start booting for the first time?

Comment: I know you asked for Ubuntu, but nonetheless: I believe, that the Archlinux image for Raspberrypies can be setup up entirely without a screen. There the SSH service is enabled right after the first boot and you can use it to set everything up. With SSH you can install any software, including a VNC viewer as suggested by Thomas W.

Comment: @potAito This isn't U&L - I think they want Ubuntu not other distros based on the site they posted to :P

Comment: @ThomasW. So? It's a pointer. If you want to set up a distro without a monitor, one option is to have the ssh service running on first boot. If that is what he wants, I'm sure it's possible to figure out how to modify an Ubuntu image to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

The RPi first boot needs to use the already embedded outputs to get the first setup done.  I highly doubt your laptop has the ability to use its monitor for external device displays.

Once configured you can install a VNC server on the RPi and then use VNC Viewer to access the display over the network (similar to a Remote Desktop type of experience)